# Set row as another row - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
 mysql_query("
    UPDATE users SET

    `clicks_yesterday`=`clicks_today`,`clicks_today`=0)
```

My structure in my database looks like this: [image: Database Structure]

My question is, how can I do so whenever I run the query above, clicks_yesterday get's the value of clicks_today?

Regards

Comment: are you just missing a " at the end after 0" before )  `clicks_today`=0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you do it. assignments in SQL are evaluated in the order encountered (e.g. left -> right). But if you want to be ENTIRELY sure that things are assigned properly, then split it into two queries:

```
UPDATE users SET clicks_yesterday = clicks_today;
UPDATE users SET clicks_today = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL what you have written works. It is however different on different DBs so it's important to test.

These are my tests for this question

```
CREATE TABLE `duals` (
  `one` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `two` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

insert into duals values (1, 2);

select * from duals;
+------+------+
| one  | two  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+

update duals set one = two, two = 0;

select * from duals;
+------+------+
| one  | two  |
+------+------+
|    2 |    0 |
+------+------+
```